# Unable to override LoginController's authFail()

Tags: grails, spring-security, authentication

I need to customize message so I tried to modify the LoginController by simply overriding the grails .plugin.springsecurity.LoginController

I have thrown AccountNotApprovedException from my customizedAuthenticationProvider.

Can someone suggest me what I am missing?

```
class AccountNotApprovedException extends AuthenticationException{

    public AccountNotApprovedException(String message, Throwable t) {
        super(message, t)
    }

    public AccountNotApprovedException(String message) {
        super(message)
    }

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public AccountNotApprovedException(String message, Object extraInformation) {
        super(message, extraInformation)
    }
}
```

I override the loginController:-

```
class LoginController extends grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController {


    def authenticationTrustResolver

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the springSecurityService.
     */
    def springSecurityService


    def authfail() {

        //my customized code
    }



}
```

And when springSecurity runs then it didn't call my overridden authFail()

Comment: add the @Override annotation it will generate an error message if it isn't overriding correctly.

Comment: Try setting `grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl` to the URL of your controller/action in your configuration.